# Disable hours from list with specific time interval

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to disable a user defined hour/minute range.

```
<div class="wrap_time">
    <h4>Time Interval added by user (in minutes)</h4>
    <input type="text" id="interval" value="90"/>
</div>

<p>Input converted to hour: <span class="convHour">0</span>:<span class="convMin">0</span></p>

<ul class="time_slot">
<li><span class="times">08:00</span></li>
<li><span class="times">08:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">08:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">08:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:00</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:00</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">11:00</span></li>
</ul>
```

The main idea is skip the first hour available and then remove the interval added by the user. I have already converted the input value to hour format, now I'm trying to remove the interval in the list of available time slot.

So, the user has insert 90 minutes of interval. Then, we have to remove the hours after the first one available in the list.

```
`<ul class="time_slot">
<li><span class="times">08:00</span></li> 
<li><span class="times">08:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">08:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">08:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:00</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">09:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:00</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:15</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">10:45</span></li>
<li><span class="times">11:00</span></li>
</ul>`
```

**The result should be**

```
`<ul class="time_slot">
<li><span class="times">08:00</span></li> 
<li><span class="times">09:30</span></li>
<li><span class="times">11:00</span></li>
</ul>`
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple use moment-locale.js for time calculation and jquery.

try below example,

```js
var i = 0;
while(i < 12)
{
  var abc = moment.utc(i+':00','hh:mm').add(1,'hour').format('hh:mm');
  var abc1 = moment.utc(abc,'hh:mm').add(30*i,'minutes').format('hh:mm');
  console.log(abc1);
  i = i+1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer me. But that wasn't what I was looking for.

I have endup with the following:

`var total_slot = $('.time_slot').length;
var interval = $("#interval").val(); // interval converted to hour

for(j=1; j < total_slot; j++){
 for(k=0; k < interval; k++){
  $(".times").eq(j).hide();
  j++;
 }
} `